Excluding a substring in dynamics 365 in the workflow editor
I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to filter strings in Dynamics 365 that do not contain a certain substring. Our filters are limited to contains, begins with, is, and is not. I've tried using regular expressions to exclude substrings, but this doesn't work in the workflow editor. Any tricks or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I have tried using regex but would not work in the workflow editor.

I'm sure that it's not possible to do it in a classic workflow designer.
You can try to use this community tool to achieve this:
https://github.com/demianrasko/Dynamics-365-Workflow-Tools/blob/master/docs/String%20Functions.md
